# In oracledb How to retrieve the column names of the REF CURSOR output from cursor.execute?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, python-oracledb

Below is the code I tried which is working fin if I change

```
column_names by column_names = ['Col1','Col2','Col3']
```

But I need it to be dynamic because the number and the name of the columns can change depending on the procedure I want to execute.

```
cursor.execute(GET_Transaction_History, date_value=date_value, cursor=ref_cursor)
column_names = [desc[0] for desc in ref_cursor.description]

df = pd.DataFrame(ref_cursor.getvalue(), columns=column_names)
```

The below line throw the following error :

```
column_names = [desc[0] for desc in ref_cursor.description]
```

AttributeError: 'Var' object has no attribute 'description'

So I wonder how to retrieve column names properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a REF CURSOR returned from a PL/SQL procedure.

The following PL/SQL procedure:

```sql
drop table t purge;
create table t (IntCol number, StringCol varchar2(4), DateCol date);

insert into t (IntCol, StringCol, DateCol) values (1, 'abcd', sysdate);
insert into t (IntCol, StringCol, DateCol) values (2, 'efgh', sysdate);
commit;

create or replace procedure myrefcursorproc2 (rc out sys_refcursor) as
begin
    open rc for select IntCol, StringCol from t;
end;
/
```

can be used like:

```py
import getpass
import os

import oracledb

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}@{cs}: ')

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        ref_cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.callproc("myrefcursorproc2", [ref_cursor])
        column_names = [desc[0] for desc in ref_cursor.description]
        print(column_names)
```

Running this gives the column names for the REF CURSOR:

```
Enter password for cj@localhost/orclpdb1: 
['INTCOL', 'STRINGCOL']
```